# Convert NGINX rewrite rules to Apache htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx

I have a client who is moving away from an NGINX webserver to Apache. Everything is simple nothing complicated however since I'm an NGINX kinda guy I forgot how to convert the NGINX rewrite rules onto apache ones.

For example, these are the NGINX rewrites

```
rewrite ^/Tower-Topics-Calendar/?$ https://$host/events/ permanent;
```

How would I convert something like that onto `.htaccess` to use with Apache?

Comment: Try this htaccess generator: https://www.htaccessredirect.net/?_ga=2.121889612.690315383.1609015261-2047964097.1609015261

Comment: Thanks! I Will do that! Although I tried a similar converter and it didn't work

Comment: Please describe the required rule in natural language. As it stands, it requires the answerer to correctly interpret the Nginx rule, as well as knowing the Apache equivalent.

Comment: This question should not have been closed - it is not "about general computing hardware and software". This question relates directly to the web application and requires code in the application space.

Comment: I don't think that this question is in any way related to programming. Also, it does not show any attempts to resolve the problem

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> rewrite ^/Tower-Topics-Calendar/?$ https://$host/events/ permanent;
> ```

This looks like an external 301 redirect from `/Tower-Topics-Calendar` (with and without a trailing slash) to `https://<host>/events/` - where `<host>` is the same hostname from the request and you specifically state the HTTPS protocol in the target.

In `.htaccess` you can achieve this using mod_rewrite. For example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^Tower-Topics-Calendar/?$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/events/ [R=301,L]
```

Note the absence of the slash prefix in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.

However, if you don't specifically need to include the HTTPS scheme (ie. this is already canonicalised) then you can use a single mod_alias `RedirectMatch` directive instead. For example:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^Tower-Topics-Calendar/?$ /events/
```

OR, to include the HTTPS protocol, you need to hardcode the hostname:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^Tower-Topics-Calendar/?$ https://example.com/events/
```